# Run doOnNex on ja BehaviorSubject in certain thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, rx-java

so first I will show you what I have and what I think happens there:

I have a `BehavourSubject<DataObject>`:

```
private BehaviorSubject<DataObject> dataSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

I give it back in a certain function that looks like this:

```
public Observable<DataObject> pendingData() {
    return this.dataSubject.asObservable()
        .doOnNext(data -> {
            // do something with this data that has to be thread save.
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

What I assume that happens is, that the doOnNext part will be run in the same Thread, in that `this.dataSubject.onNext(data);` is called. But as I do something that has to be thread save in this lambda, I should either put it into a semaphore or run all the `doOnNext` actions in a certain thread.

My first Idea is the "normal way to handle threads in rx" but I don´t know as it works.
I thought to add a `subscribeOn(certainBackgroundScheduler)` to the observable like this:

```
public Observable<DataObject> pendingData() {
    return this.dataSubject.asObservable()
        .doOnNext(data -> {
            // do something with this data that has to be thread save.
        })
        .subscribeOn(certainBackgroundScheduler)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

But when I create an Observable with an subscription block, then this block is running in that `backgroundScheduler`. When I call `onNext` on the subscriber i call it in that thread which is logical, but is it the same in the BehaviorSubject?

Is it really that simple? If not, how can I force the subject to run the `doOnNext` block in my certainThread?

Comment: And when you try it, does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to have multiple `observeOn` in your chain which let's you route values between different execution "locations".

```
dataSubject
.observeOn(backgroundScheduler)
.doOnNext(v -> /* this will run on another scheduler. */)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnNext(v -> /* this will run on main after the previous */)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really that simple? If not, how can I force the subject to run the doOnNext block in my certainThread?

Yes, it is. Read the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) about `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` for further clarification.

Comment: So the `doOnNext` block is executed in the thread that is passed by the `observeOn` method, not the `subscribeOn` method?

Comment: I was a bit wrong. So in your last code snippet `.doOnNext` is executed on a `certainBackgroundScheduler`. You can check this easily with `Thread.currentThread()` method. So, as doc says, by default your work is observed on a scheduler that you subscribed.

Comment: You could edit your answer so that it is the right one?

Comment: Edited my post.